# Find Specific Color in an Image

Tags: java, image-processing, pattern-matching, color-picker

I have an image where I want to find a specific location (coordinate) based on its color. For example [image] 
I want to find coordinates of edges of this Black box.

**How can i detect Black color in this image in Java?**

*Note: My target is to develop a program to detect eyes in a face*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) is used in image processing. With that you get your picture in frequency domain that represents a signal (in case of image signal is two dimensional). You can use Fast Fourier Transform algorimth ([FFT in java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/97data/FFT.java.html), [Fun with Java, Understanding FFT](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3457251)). There's a lot of papers about eye detection issue you can read and take inspiration from:

- http://www.jprr.org/index.php/jprr/article/viewFile/15/7
- http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~bfasel/papers/avbpa_face.pdf
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.2226&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [threshold filter](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html?page=3) and then convert image to [1-bit format](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Ditheringa24bitRGBimagetoamonochrome1bitorbilevelimage.htm). This should do the trick.

However locating eyes in image is much more harder. You might be interested in open source OpenCV library. Here is port dedicated for Java - [javacv](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). And [C++ example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/eyes.aspx) of face detection using OpenCV.